# If $H$ < $Aut_K(F)$ prove that $H$* = $\{f \in F | h(f) = f, h \in H\}$ is a subfield of F containing K.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

The question is as follows:

> Given that F is a field, and K is a subfield of F.
>
> If $H$ < $Aut_K(F)$ prove that $H$* := $\{f \in F | h(f) = f, \forall h \in H\}$ is a subfield of F containing K.

Note that $Aut_K(F)$ = $\{\phi:F \to F\; |\; \phi(k) = k, \; \forall k \in K, $ and $  \phi $ is an automorphism$ \}$

In previous parts to this question, I have already shown that $Aut_K(F)$ is a group under composition and that if K < E < F (all fields), then $Aut_E(F) < Aut_K(F)$.

I've been working on this for a few hours, and I can't figure it out.

I understand that H contains automorphisms, whereas H* contains elements from F. But I fail when I try to prove that H* is a field. Specifically, for both multiplication and addition, I can't determine why H* is closed or why inverses exist in H*.

Also, I'd love to know more about H. Is H itself an automorphic group similar to that of $Aut_K(F)$?

Comment: Your definition of $H^*$ is weird in my view. I would expect $..,\forall h\in H$ instead of $..,h\in H$. If I am correct then you can write $H^*$ as intersection, and each of the participants (a set of fixed points of some $h\in H$) can be shown to be a field.

Comment: You are correct that it was supposed to be $\forall h \in H$. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

There's pretty much only ever one way to prove closure. Assume $x$ and $y$ are in $H^*$, let $z=x+y$, and try to prove $z$ is in $H^*$. So, let $h$ be in $H$. Then $h(z)=h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)=x+y=z$. Thus, $z$ is in $H^*$. Thus, $H^*$ is closed under addition.

Now, you do multiplication.

Comment: Okay wow, this was much easier than I thought. I am still stuck with showing that the additive and multiplicative inverses exist, though. How can I guarantee that $h_1,h_2 \in H$ \ $\{0,1\} \Rightarrow h_1h_2 = 1$?

Comment: You don't have to prove that (and the last line you wrote doesn't make a lot of sense..). For additive inverse for example: if $x$ is in $H*$ and $y$ is the additive inverse of $x$ (i.e. $x+y = 0$) then for all $h \in H$, $h(x+y) = h(x)+h(y) = x+h(y) = h(0) = 0 = x+y$ so $h(y) = y$, got it?

Comment: Yeah, that mostly makes sense. How do you know that $x + h(y) = h(0)$?

Comment: What he knows is that $h(x+y)=h(0)$, since $x+y=0$.